# request ends up in 404 not found mern project

Tags: reactjs, express, proxy, request, mern

When making a request from my react application to my express application the request fails and says 404 not found. What I am doing is running my express application on `5000` and my react app on `3000`.

I put a `proxy` in `package.json` in my react app `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"`

```
export const signup = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };

  const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });

  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post('/auth/signup', body, config);
    dispatch({ type: REGISTER_SUCCESS, payload: data });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    dispatch({ type: AUTH_ERROR });
  }
};
```

then in my react app in my `actions` I try to register a user. This is where my error occurs. I see that I do get the right data passed into this function and if I run my express app and make my request through postman instead of my react app it all works fine. I am not at home and I am working on wifi from Starbucks not sure if this makes a difference at all.

Here is the error I am receiving...

```
POST http://localhost:3000/auth/signup 404 (Not Found)
Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js:66)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are sending the POST request to your react app.

Try this instead:

```
const { data } = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/auth/signup', body, config);
```

Comment: Tried doing a `get` request and doesn't work. Plus, this shouldn't be the issue because I am using a `proxy`. Also, I did try this as well just in case before and doesn't work.

Comment: make sure that the http method from express side is `post` not something else and the routes is similar.

Comment: all those are good. I have tripled check those too.

Comment: I have also tried deleting node_modules folder for my react app and package lock file and reinstalled everything. still it is not working.

Comment: Does it show 404 on all APIs ?